# eclipse plugin missing in hadoop-1.2.1

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, cygwin, hadoop-plugins

I am trying to install hadoop on Windows. Following all the steps provided on http://v-lad.org/Tutorials/Hadoop/13.5%20-%20copy%20hadoop%20plugin.html 
I am facing a problem installing the hadoop-plugin. The hadoop version downloaded from apache.org(hadoop-1.2.1.tar.gz) does not contain the 'eclipse-plugin' folder in 'hadoop-1.2.1/contrib/'

Is there any other way that I can get this done.

Thanks

Comment: Eclipse plugins are not provided in newer version of Hadoop. I am also surprised that why its not there.

Answer (score 3):

The folder might be **src**/contrib/eclips-plugin (not just contrib/eclips-plugin)

Try taking it from http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/tags/release-1.2.1/src/contrib/eclipse-plugin/

Use http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/tags/ for other releases