# eclipse plugin for hadoop 1.2.1 ubuntu

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, hadoop

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and installed hadoop 1.2.1 version. I have configured it to run on local set up successfully. I would like to use eclipse plugin for map reduce so that I can program in eclipse IDE instead of command line. I dont see the general hadoop-eclipse-plugin-*.jar file in the hadoop-1.2.1/src/contrib/eclipse-plugin location or hadoop-1.2.1/contrib location. Any help how to setup hadoop 1.2.1 mapreduce plugin for Eclipse 3.7.2?

Comment: This is one of the most common questions tagged **Hadoop+Eclipse**. Please try searching for it. You'll get tons of info.

Comment: possible duplicate of [eclipse plugin missing in hadoop-1.2.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18546052/eclipse-plugin-missing-in-hadoop-1-2-1)